# How to use Jmeter Response/Xpath assertion For Dynamically changing elements?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to use Jmeter Response/Xpath assertion  For Dynamically changing elements? please explain with example.

API Response first time

```
<Product> 
  <Name>Formal_shirt</Name>   
  <Price>1245.000000</Price>
```

API Response another time

```
<Product> 
  <Name>Tshirt</Name>          - Dynamically change
  <Price>1789.000000</Price>   - Dynamically change
```

Answer (score 1):

Given response is different each time you will not be able to check the exact name and price of the product, however you will be able to check if:

- response matches a certain [XSD schema](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) (contains elements which it needs to contain and doesn't contain any extra stuff, data types are matching, number and order of elements, etc. It can be done using [XML Schema Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XML_Schema_Assertion)
- response contains the following tags:

  - `//Product/Name`
  - `//Product/Price`

also there are numerous options like checking the number of occurrences, checking response is not null, price is above zero, etc. It can be done using [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion)

Reference material:

- [Assertions - JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: price is above zero can be done using xpath assertion //Product/Price[text()>0]   right ? how to write if response is not null for this example?

Comment: @lak using regular expression, can be chkd not null condition